# Can't Switch from Windows 7 to MacOs by holding option key when restarting

Tags: windows-7, macos, reboot

i cant switch to **OsX** from ***windows 7*** by pressing the **option** key when restarting. It worked earlier but then it suddenly stopped working.
Does anyone have a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: Need more info - precisely what Mac, what macOS? APFS will prevent you switching at boot on some machines; have to set it in the CP before reboot.

Comment: Please say what version of macOS (a.k.a. OS X) you have, what hardware you have, and any other relevant details.  For example, the history of the problem. Obviously you have a Mac with dual-boot (it would be nice if you would explicitly state even obvious stuff like that).  Is this an “old” problem, that has existed for as long as you’ve had dual boot, or is it new? What changed in the system around the same time this problem appeared?  What happens if you reboot without pressing the Option key? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My macOS is version 10.9.5. btw i inserted a blank disk and reboot and held option key. this gave me an option to choose to boot up in OSX or Windows.
this fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, try to see if you have the latest version of macOS or current latest update of the OS you want to use. If that's the case go into your `System Preferences->Startup Disk`and check which one is your default boot OS. If you don't see it or can't change it, then try a `Disk Repair` with `Disk Utility`. If these still don't work, then you might have to re-install Windows through BootCamp again so that macOS recognizes that there's a VM machine. Hope that helps. Another option is to re-install macOS (which I recommend because you won't lose any file in doing so compared to re-installing Windows completely where you have much more chances of losing your files if you didn't back it up to iCloud in Windows).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)